# what this samlssoTokenId used for can it be used for refresh session and get new SAML certificate?

Tags: wso2, session-cookies, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am  evaluating WSO25.0.0 , require token based access authentication and authorization

Using wso2 5.0.0 Identity Server,  for web  sso with SAML2 , when I send SAML request to wso2 using Idpurl

https://localhost:9443/samlsso

from  browser I found it have samlssoTokenId cookie, with some expire time
Can this cookie token can be used for getting new SAML certificate,
which will used further for authentication and authorization.

what this samlssoTokenId cookie used for can it be used for refresh session?

I am giving scenario:

for example  I have two web application ,

user is login from web app1  get samlSSOTokenId from wso2,

In web app code store this cookie token in http authorization header,

when same user request for any resource for web app2 , 
with samlssoTokenId in authorization header ,

web app 2 verify this token from wso2 server get a new SAML cetificate , and

give permission to user for accessing resource.

any suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smalssoTokenId is a cookie, and it's used by WSO2 Identity Server (IS) to find user's SAML session.

This cookie is set by IS, so browser will automatically take that to IS whenever a request goes there. That means, if user already has a SAML session at IS side, when s/he tries to access another Service Provider this cookie will be sent to IS with that SP's SAML request. Then IS can find this user's existing SAML session and provide SSO.

*Since this cookie is stored in the browser, it is not exposed to web apps.*

Comment: Hi drox, just a quick one to avoid question duplicates: how would this explanation change if you have your application sitting behind multiple servers behind a load balancer. Would this token ID be enough to perfom or rather simulate )Auth2? Thanks