# SAML logout is not happening in wso2Is

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I have received the SAML assertion xml file when I have logged in.From the saml Assertion XML file i have taken the sessionID,issuer attributes and passed to the logout request. 
       logout request xml is forming correctly 
    Super
Adminadmin22980796-7197-4505-8a4d-6d55dc391fa4

But after these it is giving error "ssoTokenId cookie not found in the logo
ut request" .

How can i solve these issue???

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the cookie samlssoTokenId[1] for the logout request which is set to your browser when login.

[1] [what this samlssoTokenId used for can it be used for refresh session and get new SAML certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004212/what-this-samlssotokenid-used-for-can-it-be-used-for-refresh-session-and-get-new)
[2] http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2016-February/059799.html

Comment: I have the issue, because I am using the request_path_auth, not the servlet. So my browser doesn't have a cookie stored on auth request. Which will definitely be not availed on further use case. How can we handle in such scenario. Is that Id-mannually created, or is it from the IS?